# C++ - Casting variables and how does it treat them?

Tags: c++, memory, casting

I've been pretty curious about this for awhile now maybe I am 100% wrong, but when you cast one type to another does it look at the memory/value and then treat that memory/value as the new type?

For example:

```
char Letter = 'A';
int iLetter = static_cast<int>(Letter);
//iLetter is 65
```

If this is correct does it look at the memory location / value of "Letter" and then change the value to represent what ever you are casting it to? I came to this theory by picturing all values as integers and then being casted to the char/struct/class etc.

Hopefully this is a full question, I'd just like a good understanding of how casting really works with the values / information to change them into new values, etc.

Comment: Well, it's going to be somewhat difficult to convert something to something else without looking at it, so obviously the value of `Letter` will be "looked" at here.

If you're asking whether the value of `Letter` is changed somehow, here, the answer would be "no".

Comment: Not if the value of "Letter" was changed, but I was wondering how "casting " works to receive a int value out of "Letter". If that makes sense, sorry if I didn't word it correctly.

Comment: The *cast* tells the *compiler* how to store the result. The `=` operator does the looking-at, at runtime.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, phenonenon of "looking" explained in very simple terms :-D ... thanks to OP and you for bringing joy in learning.

Comment: Bear in mind that a `char` is a small integer , there is no change to the value in casts like this unless the original value was actually out of range for the target type

Comment: `Letter` is also 65, it is simply stored in a location which can represent a `char` data type. On an x86 machine, the line `int iLetter = static_cast<int>(Letter)` and `int iLetter = Letter` would both likely generate a `movsbl` instruction (https://godbolt.org/g/b3cBw5)

Answer (score 3):

In situations when you cast a value (as opposed to a pointer or a reference) the compiler constructs a new value from the one being cast, as opposed to interpreting an existing location as the new type.

Specifically, the code looks at the value of `Letter`, which is a `char`, and constructs an `iLetter` from it by extending the `char` to an `int` using the [integer conversion rules of C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). This may include sign extension for signed types, so a negative `signed char` will become a negative `int`.

On the other hand, when you cast a pointer, the same location is interpreted as a new type.

Comment: note: The pointer casting situation is somewhat more complicated than that summary, e.g. multiple inheritance casts, unaligned casts

Comment: Agree with above; the brief description at the top really only applies to reinterpret cast. Might be better to rephrase.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, static_cast create temp variable with new type and then set it in iLetter.

Edit:
It means static_cast doesn't change the main var type and just read it. at the end, it doesn't directly put the converted value inside iLetter. it will create temp var with new type and that will be set inside iLetter.

Comment: What does this answer mean?

Comment: Variables always have names - "temporary value" or just "value" would be better terminology

Answer (score 0):

What your cast is doing is an [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), and that means the cast is redundant and not needed, just do this:

```
int iLetter = Letter; //This is a safe conversion as well
```

> If this is correct does it look at the memory location / value of "Letter"

Yes. Obviously, the value of Letter is looked at, as in the value of the variable seen, otherwise the compiler would have no idea what you are talking about.

> - and then change the value to represent whatever you are casting it to?

The original value is not changed, only copied, and that value is casted to the `int`, to return the character code.

Comment: How is the value of letter "looked at"? That makes it sound as though the code somehow performs a special inspection, but we can see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/b3cBw5) that the compiler recognized that the conversion is safe and the value isn't "looked at", in the sense of receiving special consideration, in any way.

Comment: The cast is doing an **explicit** conversion. The code without the cast is doing an **implicit** conversion.